# knitr how to get data into knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I have an r-script that generates a dataframe in the Global Environment of RStudio.  This data frame is about 10M observations and is sourced from a download.  I am using the imbedded knit function of RStudio however, the knit run cannot find my data.  Thus, it appears, and Google has confirmed, the knit run in RStudio launches another pid that has no awareness of the existing RStudio pid and its global environment.  My question is: How do I get that dataframe to knitr?  I have tried save()/load but the df <-load(df) just provides a character name reference to the data, not the actual data itself.  What is the best approach to making computed dataframes available to knitr?

Comment: This 'intro to working with Rmarkdown files' tutorial explains the issue and provides potential solutions: https://sites.calvin.edu/scofield/courses/m145/materials/sld/RMarkdown_DataIO.html

Comment: For a single object, prefer `saveRDS` and `readRDS`  to `save` and `load`. Either way, when you save the file, you write it to disk and give it a file name. When you read/load it, you need to read that file name, not the old object name. `saveRDS(your_data, "path/to/your_file.rds")`, then in knitr: `my_data <- readRDS("path/to/your_file.rds")`.